# Cannot read property from component when separating out code

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I would like to seperate out the following code into a Component file and import it and use it (e.g. `<ModsListing/>`).

However taking my code & putting it into a component file and importing it and using it, I get a "not defined" error.

```
         {this.props.mods.map(Mod => // Get our mods & loop over them
             <li style={{paddingBottom:'4pt'}} className="list-group-item" key={Mod.id}>
             <Link prefetch href={`/mods/${Mod.id}`}><a>


            {Mod.name}</a></Link>
            {Mod.description}

             </li>

         )}
         </ul>
```

This is the component file that I'm attempting to split it into

import React from 'react'

```
         {this.props.mods.map(Mod => // Get our mods & loop over them
        <li style={{paddingBottom:'4pt'}} className="list-group-item" key={Mod.id}>
         <Link prefetch href={`/mods/${Mod.id}`}><a>


         {Mod.name}</a></Link>
         {Mod.description}

         </li>

         )}
         </ul>
```

);

export default ModListing;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it like this

> import React from 'react'

```
    {this.props.mods&&this.props.mods.map(Mod => // Get our mods & loop over them
   <li style={{paddingBottom:'4pt'}} className="list-group-item" key={Mod.id}>
    <Link prefetch href={`/mods/${Mod.id}`}><a>


    {Mod.name}</a></Link>
    {Mod.description}

    </li>

    )}
```

);

export default ModListing;

Comment: Thanks Shunker, getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: `<ModsListing mods={this.state...}/>`